# 8 bit octal full adder help

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture, adder

*I have this project listen below and im not sure where to start maybe someone can give me a few pointers or perhaps point me in the right direction of starting this?
Thanks!!*

**Input:** A, B = octal digits (see representation below); Cin = binary digit

**Output:** S = octal digit (see representation below); Cout = binary digit

Task: ***Using binary FAs, design a circuit that acts as an octal FA***. More specifically, 
this circuit would input the two octal digits A, B, convert them into binary numbers, add 
them using only binary FAs, convert the binary result back to octal, and output the sum as 
an octal digit, and the binary carry out.

**Input/Output binary representation of octal digits**

Every octal digit will be represented using the following 8-bit binary representation:

Octal     8-bit Input Lines:

**Digit:**     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0              1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1            0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 
2            0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0 
3            0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 
4            0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 
5            0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
6            0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
7            0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1

You  are  required  to  design  the  circuit  in  a  structured  way.

Comment: Interesting. So what did you try? What did you consider and didn't try and why? Do you have any idea where to start? Here we generally expect to see a bit of effort on the OP's side for this type of questions.

Comment: I am kind of lost on it. I just need a kick start i looked into some videos but im lost at where to start.

Comment: "You are required to ..." sounds like homework. It is bad style to post homework questions without a [homework] tag.

Comment: 8 lines is not really an "octal digit". It's "unary code". If you four more lines, you can go to 11. The trick here is to use an 8x3 multiplexer to turn this into a three bit binary number. Two such  numbers can be fed into an adder to produce a four bit result. The four bit result can be used to drive the inputs of an decoder chip for a 7 segment LED display to show the result in hex.

Comment: @Kaz - "It is bad style to post homework questions without a [homework] tag." No it isn't. **The [homework] tag is deprecated.** Tags are supposed to indicate what topics the question is related to.

Comment: Sorry i wentahead to tag it as HW

Comment: @mystycs this site is not meant to solve your homeworks, did you do some work on it? Adding a bounty doesn't make this question less of a homework

Comment: I am just not sure how to do it, he project deadline passed anyway i just really want to learn and figure this out.

Comment: Did you try the way that Curd suggested?

Comment: @stevenvh Is the homework tag deprecated stack-exchange-wide or just here?

Comment: That's not an octal representation, it is a 1-hot representation.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

- Convert the input digit representation to binary (3 bits) for each of both digits using two 3 bit [encoders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_encoder#Simple_encoder).
- add both 3 bit digits using a 3 bit [adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29)
- convert the result back to the required representation using a 4 bit [decoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoder)

Comment: 2 to 4 bit decoder or 4 to 16?

Comment: @mystycs: the ouput of the adder has 4 bits (including the carry bit). So you need a 4 to 16 decoder to convert the result into your desired representation

Answer (score 2):

Since your inputs are one-hot there's no need to use a Priority encoder at the input stage, just OR' the inputs together that should drive each output bit. This is more friendly on the synthesis tool. Take a look at "Advanced Synthesis Cookbook - Altera" Section 4-1 http://www.altera.com/literature/manual/stx_cookbook.pdf

You will find sample code for the adders and output encoder too.